# Troubles with making an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I was asked to make a fleet of tractors in a class through using an array and I keep getting errors when I try to create an array of objects.

Is this the right way to go about doing so and the rest of my code in wrong in the other classes or if I'm just not using the correct way to make an array of objects?

```
package testTractor;
class TestFleet {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

      Tractor tractor = new Tractor();
      Loader loader = new Loader();
      Harvester harvester = new Harvester();

      Tractor[] fleet = new Tractor[3];

      fleet[0] = new tractor();

      fleet[1] = new loader();

      fleet[2] = new harvester();


}

  }
```

Comment: Which errors do you get ? Also, the name of your classes have an upper case first letter (as they should), but you call constructors with lower case first letters : `new tractor()` .

Comment: The type of your array is Tractor, so you can only have Tractor in it (and other vehicule that inherit from Tractor)

Comment: Also, the syntax to add to a tab is just tab[x] = element, no need to call new x()

Comment: The types of errors its giving me is it can't find any of the other variables at all even though there all in my other classes in the same package. and the loader/harvester both inherit from the tractor class

Comment: try doing `fleet[0] = tractor`

Answer (score 1):

1. When you define array, you give it a type:

   `Tractor[] fleet = new Tractor[3];`

   You will have an array of 3 elements of type `Tractor`. That's why you receive an error when you try to add element of type `Loader`. You can add just one type ( point 3 ).
2. When you try to add the elements:

   `fleet[0] = new tractor();`

   This is wrong - the casing - this way you refer to a varible, not to the class. You can't instanciate from a varible ( at least no like this ). If you change the casing you will refer to the `class Tractor`:

   `fleet[0] = new Tractor();`
3. Basic OOP - in order all of this to work like I suppose you intend, add a class `Vehicle`. Every class that extends Vehicle, will be a vehicle, so could be safely added to your array:

   `class Vehicle{}`

   and extend it all of the other classes:

   `public class Tractor extends Vehicle { ... }`

This way you could add more 'vehicles' like 'Car', 'Truck' or whatever ...

In the end:

```
Vehicle[] fleet = new Vehicle[3];
fleet[0] = new Tractor();
fleet[1] = new Loader();
fleet[2] = new Harvester();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Tractor[] fleet = new Tractor[3];
fleet[0] = tractor;
fleet[1] = loader;
fleet[2] = harvester;
```

P.S. Edited (use Object[] if Loader and Harvester do not extend Tractor)

Comment: Ok, legit. But then what ... what your array of objects could do ? A better solution is to use either extend a class or implement an interface.

Comment: @Bakudan Sure... I'll probably made a BigGuys interface to group tractors, loaders and harvesters. But in the posted code it's not clear if Loader extends Tractor - and Tractor for sure it's not an interface).

Comment: Yes, but I bet you could do more / better :) I could suggest even more complicated ;p - abstract class Vehicle implementing inteface. This way you will guarantee all of the common actions and even if you are generous to the user of your class, you could add a base implementation.